# Using Google Calendar API with secondary calendars resulting in "Invalid Value" error

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

I am unable to do the /clear action using Google Calendar API with a secondary calendar. I get the same error using either a javascript implementation or directly from their own API explorer at https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/clear

To reproduce this, please try the following:

- Create a secondary calendar using the calendar subdomain (or whatever method you prefer)

  - Note the ID of the calendar (looks like xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com)
- Go to their API Explorer for the call: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/clear
- Enter your calendar id in the field on the right labeled "calenderId".
- Enable "OAuth 2", Disable "API Key".
- Tap the EXECUTE button at the bottom.

I get the error 400 "Invalid Value". I've tried this on multiple unrelated accounts with the same result. This seems to be a serious flaw. Has anyone had success with the /clear endpoint for secondary calendars as specified by the calendarId?

Right at the top it clearly says "Primary Calendar", but then it seems a little nuts to also need to provide a calendar ID. *sigh*

Comment: I mean it may be counter-intuitive, but I don't know if stack overflow is going to help you figure out this endpoint. If you think the documentation should be changed to be clearer you can just go ahead and submit a bug at [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

Comment: You are right.  Was just frustrated at the API itself missing the someone obvious ability to clear a secondary calendar.